# How To Create Proxy For OSGi Service

Tags: java, osgi

Let's say I have a really simple interface for getting files from somewhere:

```
interface FileManager {

    File getFile(Object data);
}
```

We can assume there are multiple implementations of this interface and all applications only use the interface and are blissfully unaware of which implementation the OSGi context provides them with.

Since some methods to get files are really slow, I want to add an optional cache. But I don't want the applications to change from the `FileManager` interface to another one, since that would make them aware of which implementation they are using (and if it's slow or not).

So I came up with this:

```
class FileManagerCache implements FileManager {

private final Map<Object, File> cache = new HashMap<>();

public File getFile(final Object data) {
    if (this.cache.containsKey(data)) {
        return this.cache.get(data);
    }
    final File result = getDelegate().getFile(data);
    this.cache.put(data, result);
    return result;
}

private FileManager getDelegate() {
    for (final FileManager fileManager : ServiceUtil.findServices(FileManager.class)) {
        if (this != fileManager) {
            return fileManager;
        }
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No FileManager is present!"); //$NON-NLS-1$
}
}
```

This implementation is registered with a very high `"service.ranking"` and so the first one the applications use, and it delegates to the next one in line in the list of possible implementations.

Now this approach is not very elegant, and probably error prone. How would I create a proxy in OSGi using standard mechanisms?

Answer (score 1):

A safer way to define a proxy for another service is to use service properties.
For example you could give the slow FileManager a property like "name=A".

Then you could give the proxy the propertie name=A,cached=true. On initialization you could give the proxy a filter name=A to search for a service to proxy.

So the user of the service could either use any serivce (by ranking) or filter for cached=true if it needs the cached variant.

Comment: This would still push the responsibility of deciding which service to use to the caller who has no way of knowing which implementation he will get. Also this doesn't really work for multiple slow implementations.

Comment: At least in case of Declarative Services you can customize the filter for a service reference in a config. So it could be decided by the user. Or do you want to have a completely automatic system?

Comment: My question is more about how to create a proxy that will act as an implementation of the service interface while delegating to a unknown other implementation.

Comment: If you want to kind of replace the service for the user then take a look at this: https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/service/guard/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/service/guard/impl/GuardingEventHook.java
This module is used in karaf to secure services. It listens for services as they are created and replaces them with the security proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a service which collects registered implementation of other services? Sample implementation and the idea you can get from [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/services/impl/SampleMultiReferenceServiceImpl.java).

Comment: How does that differ from what I'm doing now: Getting all the implementations (with "all" being either zero or one service) at runtime and delegating to one of them?

Comment: It differs in the way, that you don't have to initialize the different services yourself, you just register them as OSGi service using that particular interface (you ask for OSGi standard mechanism for doing what you did). Than in your file service where you want to use your particular client/file manager you can just bind the implementation you want like this:
`@Reference(target = "(service.config-id=cachablefilemanager)")
private FileManager fileManager;`

Comment: I register the implementations as OSGi services now, too. And I want to **avoid** that the user of the `FileManager` has to know what implementation he will get. And he has to know that if he needs to qualify the `FileManager` to be cached or not.

Comment: But how would you decide which service to return to the caller? There should be some logic and somewhere this decision should be taken. Probably what you miss is some middleware service which chooses the proper implementation and this way the logic remains hidden to the caller.

Comment: There is only one implementation present in the OSGi context; it's always chosen at assembly time, not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you describe is a 2 service model because you combine multiple responsibilities. You combine the caching responsibility with the abstraction of where the file comes from. Or in other words, your design is mixing concerns and it is therefore not *cohesive*.

The easiest solution is therefore to have a `FileManager` and a `FileManagerProvider` service. You can then provide a cached File Manager and a transparent File Manager depending on your situation.

When I started in software more than 35 years ago I got coupling but it took me many years to understand how much more important cohesion is. This problem is a very archetypical example.

Now to see why this design is bad, you could implement the proxies with OSGi service hooks. You register an alternative and hide the original services. However, that is a lot of work to make a technical inferior solution, as all proxies related solutions have their own problems. Keeping it simple, straightforward, and using actual types to represent your abstractions is imho the best solution. (Though I admit I frequently find that I initially made uncohesive designs as well before I understood the problem well.)

Answer (score 0):

Felix DependencyManager supports it.

There is the summary from http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-dependency-manager/reference/component-aspect.html

> **Dependency Manager - Aspect**
>
> Aspects, as part of aspect oriented programming, can be used in a
> dynamic environment such as OSGi to "extend" existing services and add
> certain "capabilities" to them. Examples of these are adding a
> specific caching mechanism to a storage service or implementing
> logging. Aspects in OSGi can be applied to services and can be added
> and removed at runtime.
>
> Aspects allow you to define an "interceptor", or chain of interceptors for a service to add features like caching or logging, etc. An aspect will be applied to any service that matches the specified interface and filter. For each matching service an aspect will be created based on the aspect implementation class. The aspect will be registered with the same interface and properties as the original service, plus any extra properties you supply here. It will also inherit all dependencies, and if you declare the original service as a member it will be injected.

```
@AspectService(ranking=10), properties={@Property(name="param", value="value")})
class AspectService implements InterceptedService {
     // The service we are intercepting (injected by reflection)
     protected InterceptedService intercepted;

     public void doWork() {
        intercepted.doWork();
     }
 }
```